# WordPress: Custome form submission for comments not running as expected

Tags: php, wordpress, post

I have a WordPress instance where I'm required to create a custom on-site comment editing form submission. Which is meant to replace the default comment editor that redirect a user to admin panel for editing.

The code is not returning echo and when replaced with error_log the results variate.(Every time pages refreshed a different level of error is returned).

Generally speaking, any method I try I don't manage to edit the comment and I don't get any solid error to understand where is the problem.

Content of: class-walker-comment.php (I'm aware that core files are not to be tempered, but for simplicity of understanding I have used this method).

```
//Replaced for the implementation
// edit_comment_link( __( 'Edit' ), ' <span class="edit-link">', '</span>' );  

<span id="<?php comment_ID() ?>" class="edit-link"><h1>Edit</h1><span class="comment-edit-link"></span></span>

<div class="comment-edit-form" style="display: none;" id="comment-edit-form-<?php comment_ID(); ?>">
 <form id="edit-comment-form-<?php comment_ID(); ?>" action="/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/sty-processing-page.php" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="edit_comment_id" value="<?php comment_ID(); ?>" id="comment_id_<?php comment_ID(); ?>">
  <textarea name="edit_comment_content" id="edit-comment-content-<?php comment_ID(); ?>"><?php echo wp_filter_nohtml_kses(get_comment_text()); ?></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="Save Changes">
 </form>
</div>
```

---

This is where problem seems to occur, in custom plugin: sty-processing-page.php

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Custom Comment Editor
Description: A custom comment editor plugin.
Version: 1.0
Author: ME!
*/

// Hook the plugin function to run when WordPress is initialized.
add_action('init', 'custom_comment_editor_init', 99);

function custom_comment_editor_init() {

    // Check if the request method is POST.
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
        edit_comment_submission_function();
    }else {
    error_log('Post request method not called for.');
   }
}

function edit_comment_submission_function() {
    error_log('Function called');
    error_log('POST data: ' . print_r($_POST, true));

    if (isset($_POST['edit_comment_id'], $_POST['edit_comment_content'])) {
        $comment_id = intval($_POST['edit_comment_id']);
        $comment_content = sanitize_text_field($_POST['edit_comment_content']);

        $comment = get_comment($comment_id);
        if ($comment) {
            // Update the comment content
            wp_update_comment(array(
                'comment_ID' => $comment_id,
                'comment_content' => $comment_content,
            ));
            error_log('Comment updated successfully');
        } else {
            error_log('Comment not found');
        }
    } else {
        error_log('Missing edit_comment_id or edit_comment_content in POST data');
    }
}
```

What is sure regardless to the modifications I've made. Every time the sty-processing-page.php is loaded, in the console is returned:
POST https://example.com/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/sty-processing-page.php
[HTTP/2 500  12ms]

I know I'm missing something. I just don't know what I'm looking for exactly.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Enable Debugging in WordPress: Edit your wp-config.php file and set WP_DEBUG to true. This will allow WordPress to output any PHP errors directly to the browser or to a debug.log file in the wp-content directory.

php
Copy code
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
@ini_set('display_errors', 0);

Comment: The form redirects to your plugin but this is not necessary: ​​remove the *action* from the form.
I can't see a reference to *https://example.com* anywhere, so I can't figure out why it's showing up in the console. Maybe you have a reference for it somewhere else?

Comment: @user580950
Yes, I have done this. The log is populated with the following:
[05-Nov-2023 15:12:44 UTC] Missing edit_comment_id or edit_comment_content in POST data
[05-Nov-2023 15:12:56 UTC] Post request method not called for.
Like I said the logs are random. In this instance the error_log of " Missing edit_comment_id or edit_comment_content in POST data " came before " Post request method not called for. " This should not be possible since the POST method is called for first?

Comment: @Pippo Thank you so much. You saved my neck. 
Your solution of removing the action from the form worked perfectly.

Comment: I understand know where I made mistake. Since the plugin is preloaded by WordPress, it's not necessary for the redirection to the plugin on the first place. Therefor the action is not necessary. Thanks again @Pippo